Google Cloud - Integration between public and internal Cloud Run Services with External Load balancer
I have External Load balancer in project-lb and 3 Cloud Run services in project-app.

Nginx based Cloud Run service, h-service-1 configured as internet enabled, all traffic allowed
p-service-1 configured as internet enabled, all allowed
m-service-1 configured as Internal + Load Balancer

I want to establish communication between these cloud run services.  I have default network configuration.
Traffic from load balancer reaches h-service-1 and p-service-1.  p-service-1 makes a call to m-service-1.  Is a REST call to m-service-1 expected to work?
Is it must to have Serverless VPC connector or internal load balancer for integration with internet enabled cloud run services ?

Read my response on your other question, it will be clearer then!

Cloud Run already includes a load balancer called the GFE (Google Frontend). Why are you adding another? Like your other question, explain what problem you are trying to solve. Another item, why are you Nginx which is another proxy layer inside your Cloud Run application? Nginx can be useful but sometimes means a poorly designed app for Cloud Run.

I have a custom domain to be applied onto a Cloud Run service.  I had configured Managed Custom Domain approach in Cloud Run.  As I remember, I was getting 404 error.  Also, ELB path probably helped in better security.
ReactJS based app is wrapped in Nginx and served through Cloud Run.  However, I have a Cloud Run service other than this also being invoked from a ReactJs and is taken through Nginx Proxy approach.
So do you recommend custom domain (Google LB or base) approach or my ELB, why ?

If I go with Domain Mapping with Google LB option, it is an automation to introduce ELB into the project.  With my approach I am sharing my ELB for different domains.  But the ELB is in another project.
By my approach of sharing ELB, I am required to have Internet NEG for Cloud Run service and enable all traffic into it.  This is the root cause.
